# How to compare items within one column in Postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with a column

```
ColumnA
x1
x2
x3
x4
...
x100
```

How can I use postgresql to apply a function f to every two items in the column and get a result like:

```
ResultColumn
f(x1, x2)
f(x1, x3)
....
f(x1, x100)
...
f(x99, x100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Caretesian product:

```
select t1.columnA, t2.columnA, f(t1.columnA, t2.columnA)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.columnA > t1.columnA;
```

Well, this is only half a Cartesian product.